# Error using sepia image effect in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, effects

In my app, I am having an `imageView`, the image in the `imageView` should be give some effects like sepia, black and white.
To do sepia effect I used the following code,

```
 -(UIImage*)makeSepiaScale:(UIImage*)image
{
    CGImageRef cgImage = [image CGImage];
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage);
    CFDataRef bitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);
    UInt8* data = (UInt8*)CFDataGetBytePtr(bitmapData);

    int imagWidth = image.size.width;
    int imageheight = image.size.height;
    NSInteger myDataLength = imagWidth * imageheight * 4;


    for (int i = 0; i < myDataLength; i+=4)
    {
        UInt8 r_pixel = data[i];
        UInt8 g_pixel = data[i+1];
        UInt8 b_pixel = data[i+2];

        int outputRed = (r_pixel * .393) + (g_pixel *.769) + (b_pixel * .189);
        int outputGreen = (r_pixel * .349) + (g_pixel *.686) + (b_pixel * .168);
        int outputBlue = (r_pixel * .272) + (g_pixel *.534) + (b_pixel * .131);

        if(outputRed>255)outputRed=255;
        if(outputGreen>255)outputGreen=255;
        if(outputBlue>255)outputBlue=255;


        data[i] = outputRed;
        data[i+1] = outputGreen;
        data[i+2] = outputBlue;
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider2 = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, myDataLength, NULL);
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * imagWidth;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(imagWidth, imageheight, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider2, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef); // YOU CAN RELEASE THIS NOW
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider2); // YOU CAN RELEASE THIS NOW
    CFRelease(bitmapData);

    UIImage *sepiaImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef); // YOU CAN RELEASE THIS NOW
    return sepiaImage;
}
```

It is working perfectly, but only for .png image, when I use .jpg images, it just displays a black colour view for the `imageView`. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: jpg does not support 32 bits per pixel max is 24 bits which is 8 bits each for R,G,B  (no Alpha) since you did not convert the data to RGBA do the following changes:    int imagWidth = image.size.width;
    int imageheight = image.size.height;
    NSInteger myDataLength = imagWidth * imageheight * 3;


    for (int i = 0; i < myDataLength; i+=3) .... Note if you deal with grayscale images , whether PNG or JPG - this will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use core image processing,

```
 -(void)makeSepiaScale
{
CIImage *beginImage =[[CIImage alloc]initWithImage:imageForView];

    CIContext * context=[CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"
                                  keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage,
                        @"inputIntensity", @0.8, nil];
    CIImage *outImage = [filter outputImage];

    CGImageRef cgimg=[context createCGImage:outImage fromRect:[outImage extent]];


[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg]];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider to get the bitmap from JPEG:

```
-(UIImage*)makeSepiaScale:(UIImage*)image {

    CGImageRef cgJpegImage = [image CGImage];
    CGDataProviderRef jpegProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgJpegImage);

    CGImageRef cgBitmapImage = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(jpegProvider, nil, NO, kCGRenderingIntentRelativeColorimetric);
    CGDataProviderRef bitmapProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgBitmapImage);

    CFDataRef bitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(bitmapProvider);
    UInt8* data = (UInt8*)CFDataGetBytePtr(bitmapData);

    // other code to make sepia effect
}
```

You can't use JPEG encoded image like plain RGB. So, just decode it with CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider first.

Comment: I've posted the code to use for JPEG image. For PNG use the solution which works now.

Comment: it crashes at UInt8* data   ebad access

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are dealing with non RGBA format data .... JPG for one does not have an Alpha channel. Rather than deal with the intricacies of the data I suggest that you consider using  Core Image filters, I've used them with jpg and PNG without any issues.

There is a variety of Core Image filters including one for Sepia and another for grayscale / black and white   here is the code for Sepia:

```
-(UIImage*)makeSepiaScale:(UIImage*)input_image output:(UIImage *)output
{

 CIImage *cimage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:input_image];  
CIFilter *myFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"];

[myFilter setDefaults];
[myFilter setValue:cimage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[myFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8f] forKey:@"inputIntensity"];

CIImage *image = [myFilter outputImage];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:image fromRect:image.extent];
output = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];  
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
return (output);}
```

PS the Apple documentation on CoreImage is good, I suggest you read up on it.

Comment: JPG either uses an 8 bit grayscale image or 24 bit colour - which is 8 bits for r, g, and blue. Your routine presumes a 32 bit colour format known as RBGA8888 used by PNG. (Note Grayscale PNG also exist). I believe there are routines to check the CGColorSpaceRef in use or convert it to RGBA so your routine may work but why deal with that if higher level frameworks like CoreImage already does all the heavy lifting for you.